# How to get datewise breakdown of Users data from Google Analytics Reporting v4 REST API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using the below code.

```
{ reportRequests: [
                             {
                               viewId: 'XXXXXXXX',
                                 dateRanges:[ 
                                   {
                                       startDate:'2018-01-01',
                                       endDate:'2018-01-31'
                                   }
                                   ],
                               metrics: [
                                 {
                                   expression: 'ga:users'
                                 }                                   
                               ]

                             }
                           ]}
```

I'm getting the response with total values. I need to get the data broken down date wise. I tried adding dimensions date, But I'm getting an error. What is the right way to get datewise data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the date dimension to your request in order to get your results with the dates.

```
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    "viewId":"XXXX",
    "dateRanges":[
      {
        "startDate":"2018-01-01",
        "endDate":"2018-01-31"
      }],
    "metrics":[
      {
        "expression":"ga:users"
      }],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name":"ga:date"
      }]
    }]
}
```

[samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for